# SSIS package containing script task getting failed in Azure Data factory

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-factory, script-task

I have recently moved SSIS packages (with target server version as 2016) to azure SQL database.
I have followed below steps:

1. Created azure ssis IR in azure data factory
2. Created pipeline with execute SSIS package activity.

When I trigger this pipeline it gets failed.
Upon looking at SSIS package execution log, I get below error:

> Script task error:
>
> Can not load script task for execution.

I am newbie to Azure SSIS IR.
Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: What is the code in your script task?

Comment: FYI, script tasks do work, but you might need to alter them. PS I thought it was server version 2017 that you need to deploy to.

Comment: its a vb.net 2015 code to update some ssis variables and update sql statements to some tables